# Add IPFS into Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, solidity, ipfs

I'm currently finishing up the free Solidity Bootcamp with Patrick Collins. I have downloaded and installed IPFS command line, and when I check on command line, all works.

However, when I type --ipfs version into Visual Studio Code, I get

```
ipfs : The term 'ipfs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ipfs daemon
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ipfs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Usually, this means an environment variable issue  or install mess up. Has anyone encountered something like this? I can't seem to find a solid step by step diagnostic to fix this problem. I'm completely new to coding, so this could be an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. No worries. Had to restart computer.

Comment: most effectively solution :)))

Comment: this should marked as the answer